# Microwave Oven Rust -Does it affect FOOD cooked in it (hurt us?)

Tags: food-safety, equipment, microwave, kitchen-safety

Can anyone tell me if there is a toxicity effect on food cooked in a microwave oven with rust along the edges inside the microwave itself??

Answer (score 1):

Rust wouldn't contaminate the food.

The concern would be that a rusted edge could keep the oven from sealing properly and thus leaking microwave radiation into the room. There isn't any way to detect leakage without special equipment.